# Tunnel SSH from A->B->C

Tags: ssh, vnc, putty, tunneling

I'm looking to setup a tunnel using PuTTY on Windows.

Ideally I'd SSH directly from A->C, however, I can't from the network I'm on.  I can, however connected from A->B->C.

C is running a vncserver, which I'd like to connect to from A.

How can I tunnel through SSH from A->B->C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ProxyCommand.

```
ssh -A -t ruapehu.example.com ssh -A -t aoraki ssh -A tongariro
```

There's a [good article on the topic on SSHMenu](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html) (which is for Linux).

You mentioned PuTTY and so [here's something to read](http://monkeyswithbuttons.org/2010/10/ssh-proxycommand-and-putty/) after the above article.

If you meant to ssh a specific port, you can always try something like this:

```
ssh test@example.com -t -L 8042:127.0.0.1:8042 'ssh test@192.168.33.3 -t -L 8042:127.0.0.1:8042 'ssh -L 8042:192.170.1.1:80 admin@192.168.69.69
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to connect from A (vnc client) to C (vnc server) you have to run the equivalent with putty of the following ssh command (on the host A):

```
 ssh -L 5900:hostC.yourdomain.com:5900 hostB.yourdomain.com
```

This command will make a tunnel from A to B and connect directly the tunnel to your host C.

Already on the host A, you just have to launch the vnc client to the loopback address localhost:5900

Comment: This should have been chosen as the correct answer.

Comment: You need to have a tunnel running already on C? In other words, this isn't the complete command?